# ffmpeg behaviour when there is server side html upload limit

Tags: php, html, video, upload, ffmpeg

The case is the following:

There is a server side enforced limit on the size of file upload via PHP/HTML. The limit is set to 20 MB.

So without any encoding the users can upload up to 20MB videos.

My qestion is the following - Having in mind the PHP/HTML upload limit, is it possible to have the possibility for a user to choose to upload a video of 100 MB for example, then have this video encoded via ffmpeg and reduced in size of 20 MB or less for successful upload?

Thank you.

Comment: Only if the user runs ffmpeg himself.  Your PHP code runs on the _server_.

Comment: Is there any way to circumvent this upload limit? either bu ffmpeg or by other technique?

Comment: change the server limit setting, it has NOTHING to do with  ffmpeg

Comment: that's the thing - the limit is enforced by the server rules and as this is shared hosting changing the limit is not possible.
Going for VPS is a possibility but I wonder if there is a way to accomplish this without having a dedicated server.

Comment: change hosts, its the only option

Comment: ok, thanks for the help, needed some professional advice!